# WordPress site health showing REST API error

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am making a simple local wordpress website. When i go to site health. I have this Fatal problem:

Error in REST API:

An error occurred when testing the REST API:

REST API Endpoint: http://192.168.1.100:5000/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post?context=edit

REST API Response: (http_request_failed) cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10014 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

I already tried:

- disable all plugins
- check other REST Endpoints and it works fine:

  - http://192.168.1.100:5000/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
  - http://192.168.1.100:5000/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/users

But still the error wont go away. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

increase your tome out limit using max_execution_time  in php.ini file

Comment: Well I already adjusted it to a much longer time but still errors exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).